# What are "scholarly" music websites?

Tags: learning

I'm looking for some "scholarly" sources for reports for my Music class. We're studying Music History, specifically sacred vs secular classical music.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to either Jstor or the Grove Dictionary of Music, those are the first places to go.

The [Grove Dictionary of Music and Musicians](http://www.oxfordmusiconline.com/public/book/omo_gmo) is available online at the [Oxford Music Online](http://www.oxfordmusiconline.com/public/page/guided_tour) web site. The [Grove Dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Grove_Dictionary_of_Music_and_Musicians) has been published continuously since the year 1878. Subscriptions are not affordable to individuals, but certain university and public libraries pay for a subscription, so check with libraries in your area.

The Music Index also provides abstracts to articles about music that you can then find in a local library.

Comment: Reina, I added some details in the body of your answer.